# Redash Question. Filtering query based drop-down based on another query based drop-down

Tags: redash

So im working with redash.
I need to find some way to filter results of one dropdown based on the results of another dropdown.

if i select "A" in the dropdown 2, i want the results of dropdown 1 to be changed based on the option selected in dropdown 2.
Is this feature supported in Redash? i would appreciate any help in this regard.